# Can I display both (and only) month and year in a date_select helper tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select, view-helpers, datefield

I have a form with a `date` attribute.

Right now I'm using `f.date_select :begin_date, discard_day: true` but that displays month and  year in a each own's select menu respectively.

**Is it possible to have both month and year displayed in the same select menu, like below?**

2013 January
2013 February
2013 March
2013 April
etc.

Comment: if you plz post some part of code.Thx

Comment: What code part would bring clarity to my question?

Comment: view and controller related to this question might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 7 years later, but this is still is still coming up when I Googled for this exact problem.

You can make it work with a standard `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder#select` and feed it the set of month+years by hand

```rb
<% the_months = (Date.new(2020,1,1)..Date.new(2020,12,31)).select { |d| d.day == 1 } %>
<%= f.select :start_date, the_months.map { |d| [d.strftime('%b %Y'), d] } %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look to [rails API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) AND [date select method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) for more details.

Your code will be something like this:

```
<%= f.date_select :date,  { :discard_day => true} %>
```

Comment: I assume it's not possible then? As that option is not available there.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's exaclty my existing code, that I have provided in the question.

Comment: This just repeats what the original questioner said with an unhelpful "you have to read the manual" preamble.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted just one field with a datepicker where the user could only select a month and a year. Today I found out about the [month_field](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/month_field) FormHelper which solved the problem for me.

I know it's not an answer to the problem the original poster asked about but hopefully it can help others googling for the same problem.

`<%= f.month_field :date %>`